# How to configure Nginx for load balancing

Tags: python, docker, nginx, flask, docker-compose

I am learning basics of load balancing with `Nginx` below is the sample application with 3 containes (2 app and 1 nginx)

[image]

`app1` and `app2` are accessible at `127.0.0.1:5001` and `127.0.0.1:5002` respectively, but when I call `nginx` at `127.0.0.1:8081` I am getting error `502 Bad Gateway`

**Nginx Container Logs**

```
2021/02/25 10:36:33 [error] 8#8: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5001/", host: "0.0.0.0:8081", referrer: "http://0.0.0.0:9000/"
2021/02/25 10:36:33 [error] 8#8: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5002/", host: "0.0.0.0:8081", referrer: "http://0.0.0.0:9000/"
172.19.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2021:10:36:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://0.0.0.0:9000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
2021/02/25 10:36:33 [error] 8#8: *1 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://loadbalancer/favicon.ico", host: "0.0.0.0:8081", referrer: "http://0.0.0.0:8081/"
172.19.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2021:10:36:33 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://0.0.0.0:8081/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
```

Below are the relevant files

App 1 and App 2: [Dockerfile](https://pastebin.com/5rtB8bfH)

App 1: [app.y](https://pastebin.com/APTj69bS)

App 2: [app.y](https://pastebin.com/qB82g4rk)

**nginx.conf**

```
http {

    upstream loadbalancer {
        server 127.0.0.1:5001 weight=6;
        server 127.0.0.1:5002 weight=4;
    }

    server {
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://loadbalancer/;
        }
    }

}

events {
  
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  
  # Application 1
  app1:
    build: ./app1         
    image: "app1:latest"   
    container_name: app1
    ports:
      - "5001:5000"
    networks:
      - net1
  
  # Application 2
  app2:
    build: ./app2
    image: "app2:latest"
    container_name: app2
    ports:
      - "5002:5000"
    networks:
      - net1

  # Nginx
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    image: "nginx:latest"
    container_name: nginx 
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    depends_on:
      - app1
      - app2
    networks:
      - net1

networks:
  net1:
    external: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The containers from your application are on their own IP address inside the network, which can be resolved by the container name.

I have recreated your case (with minor modification since you had not shred the nginx build, so I used ubuntu container and modifed net1 to be created by `docker-compose`) and connected to the nginx container. After installing `ping` and `netcat` tools:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                     PORTS                    NAMES
d29b2a96a843   ubuntu:20.04                          "/bin/bash"              3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes               0.0.0.0:8081->80/tcp     nginx
0200de2170a0   test-ng                               "python3 app.py"         3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes               0.0.0.0:5001->5000/tcp   app1
0f1bd788a962   test-ng                               "python3 app.py"         3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes               0.0.0.0:5002->5000/tcp   app2
```

```
root@d29b2a96a843:/# ping app1
PING app1 (172.21.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from app1.test_net1 (172.21.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.126 ms
64 bytes from app1.test_net1 (172.21.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.103 ms 
^C
--- app1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.103/0.114/0.126/0.011 ms
root@d29b2a96a843:/# ping app2
PING app2 (172.21.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from app2.test_net1 (172.21.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.107 ms
64 bytes from app2.test_net1 (172.21.0.3): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.109 ms
^C
--- app2 ping statistics ---
```

To test further, I used `nc` to connect the app

```
root@d29b2a96a843:/# nc app1 5000
GET /

"App #1"
^C
root@d29b2a96a843:/# nc app2 5000
GET /

"App #1"
^C
root@d29b2a96a843:/# nc localosht 5001
nc: getaddrinfo for host "localosht" port 5001: Name or service not known
root@d29b2a96a843:/# nc localosht 5002
nc: getaddrinfo for host "localosht" port 5002: Name or service not known
```

So, in conclusion, you do not have app1 running on port `5001` inside your ngingx container (unless you have some "exotic" setup of `net1` that you had not share). This is why `nginx` is throwing the error `no live upstreams while connecting to upstream` since it can not find the port 5001 and 5002 open on the `localhost` (127.0.0.1) provided.

For your example to make it working, easiest is to modify the `nginx.conf` configuration as follows:

```
http {

    upstream loadbalancer {
        server app1:5000 weight=6;
        server app2:5000 weight=4;
    }

    server {
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://loadbalancer/;
        }
    }

}

events {
  
}
```